# AWS CLI: how to list env variables for a specific application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking for a way to list the env variables (called Environment Properties in AWS Console) for a specific application so I can compare dev and prod environments. I tried:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk retrieve-environment-info  --application-name=app_name --region us-east-1 --profile=profile  --info-type tail
```

and got:

```
Unknown options: --application-name=app_name
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the best you can do is get a list of all the Environment Variable Names:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-options --environment-name hq-staging \
--query "Options[?Namespace=='aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'][Name]" --output text
```

If you have a default value set for the environment, then you will be able to view that value:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-options --environment-name ${beanstalk_env_name} \
--query "Options[?Namespace=='aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'][Name,DefaultValue]" --output text
```